# Javascript / jQuery + length = problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

A small version of my script would be this:

```
var x = null;
for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I noticed (by doing some 'alert' debugs) that my script halts when evaluating *x.length*. Even when i try to print it in an alert, the script stops.

The idea is that somethimes my x variable is an array, sometimes is null.

Of course, I am a beginner, so probably i've done something stupid. No errors appear in my Firefox 6 error console.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var x = null;
for(var i = 0; x && i < x.length; i++) {
    //do stuff
}
```

This will first check whether `x` is not `null`. If `x` is `null`, `for` will not run. If it is not `null`, `for` will run as usual.

Comment: This is not a good way to check condition because this condition will be evaluated for every iteration in the loop which is unnecessary. First check if `x` is null and then start the loop.

Comment: come on! do you really think this can cause performance breakdown?

Comment: Not a performance breakdown but it is unnecessary check which can be avoided.

Comment: and I avoided unnecessary if :) see no difference

Answer (score 2):

In your code `x` is null and you are trying to get the `length` property from a `null` value which will throw a javascript error. Please check your console you will definitely see an error.

In such situations you should always make sure you do null check before accessing any property of the object or variable. Try this

```
var x = null;
if(x){
   for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's null. Add this if statement

```
if (x !== null){
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = null;

if(x !== null){
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {

        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you initialize `x` with `var x = [];`? This way, you can make sure that it is always an array, yet the loop won't do anything if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the method length on a null object.
So you need to test if the object is null before calling it.

```
var x = null;
if(x != null)
{
  for(var i=0; x!= null && i < x.length; i++)
  {
     //do stuff
  }
}
```

or

```
var x = null;
for(var i=0;x!= null && i<x.length; i++)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option here would be to initialize x to an object with the length property -

```
x = {
      length : 0
    };
```

instead of

```
x = null;
```

EDIT : pulsar's answer makes more sense!